# What does a mysql server id look like?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I am trying to connect to mysql server on one.com's phpmyadmin.

I am using dreamweaver setting up (atleast trying) mysql connection, but i don't know what to put in the 'mysql server' box.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be your mysql server hostname. If it's the same machine then ```localhost``` will do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for your webhost. Ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ip address (192.168.xxx.xxx) or server name.

Answer (score 0):

It's either the hostname (eg. `localhost` or `mysql.example.com`) or the IP of the server (eg. `127.0.0.1`). You can find example values in the [documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/connect-mysql-database-dreamweaver.html):

```
MySQL Server: mysql1.myDomain.com
User Name: dbuser
Password: myPassword
```